# IPhone image with clickable hotspots

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to know how to implement a clickable image for an iPhone application using objective C. I want this image to be clickable at specific areas even when it is rotated. If for instance the top of an image goes to page A, and this gets rotated clockwise by 90 degrees I want this clickable area to change accordingly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmmm, you could place `UIButton`'s (with custom backgrounds) next to each other to make up the image (like a puzzle) and then group them into a `UIView` and instead of rotating the `UIImageView` you could rotate the `UIView` which should still enable the clickable areas.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use an HTML web page with an image and map then display the image in a UIWebView.

When rotating the phone, rotate the UIWebView and let the image map do the rest.

This might not be exactly what you're after depending on the application.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically throw a transparent UIButton on top of the image wherever you want a hot spot.